# Where is all items under "All Files" in Sharepoint Designer 2010?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, file

I have opened my sharepoint site in Sharepoint Designer 2010. When I click on "All Files" which is in left panel, I see only one test.xml file. So, I just want to know How can I get all items of my site in "All Files" section?

Please help.

Note: I am having Administrator privileges to that site.

Comment: Check is there any filter on the Name,Title,Size..etc on all files view in SharePoint Designer 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is there any filter on the Name,Title,Size..etc on all files view in SharePoint Designer 2010